# What is the cost of the engine Boeing 747 Model 400?

Tags: engine

What is the cost of the engine Boeing 747 Model 400?
Including what component of the cost of the aircraft engine Gies

Comment: I do not really understand

Comment: cost of aircraft: 747-400/-400ER: USD234–266.5 million
                      747-400F/-400ERF: USD238–268 million

Comment: What does "Including what component of the cost of the aircraft engine Gies" mean?

Comment: 200 million dollars is the cost of a 747 engine?
How much does the whole plane?
I read somewhere Arbus 380 exceeds $ 400 million
Including engine and chassis .....

Comment: The engines are the cheap part, with the engine manufacturers making their money on the spares and support during the life of the aircraft. As I understand it there have been cases of airlines receiving the engines for free when a manufacturer wants to get a foot hold in that airlines engine requirements (and depending on the actual fuel consumption of the engine and other costs over its life, the airline could find taking a free engine deal is a really bad idea).

Answer (score 4):

The actual prices paid for an engine are likely to not be released publicly. However, list prices are advertised, and other sources may help give an idea of the price range for such engines. The [747-400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747-400) model has three engine options available: PW 4056, GE CF6, and RR RB211. These engines are also used on other aircraft, which will help in finding the prices.

The CF6 engine has a list price of about $11 million ([from an A330 order in 2009](http://www.geaviation.com/press/cf6/cf6_20090709.html), higher thrust version; \$12.2 million in 2015 USD<sup>1</sup>).

The PW4056 engine has a price of $5.8 million ([from a 1994 report](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kp5kYHecqZIC&lpg=PA113&dq=4056&pg=PA113#v=onepage&q=4056&f=false); \$9.3 million in 2015 USD).

I haven't found good pricing for the RB211. An older, lower thrust version was priced at £340,000 [in 1971](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_RB211) (\$4.8 million in 2015 USD<sup>2</sup>), [or you could buy one right now for $35,000](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Rolls-Royce-RB211-22B-Complete-Engine-with-Stand-/141666658773) (the seller hopes it can be put on display, mentioning "very high end art displays" but also "top dollar in scrap").

The list price for a 747-400 was about \$240 million, which means that 4 engines at a list price of \$10 million each would be about %17 of the cost of the plane.

<sub><sup>1</sup>[Inflation calculator](http://www.usinflationcalculator.com/)
<sup>2</sup>[exchange rate](https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/EXUSUK.txt)</sub>

Comment: Do they get a discount, like buy one engine, get one free?

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, \$ 5.8 million in 1994 dollars is quite different from \$ 5.8 million in 2009 or 2015 dollars.

Comment: Also, this is probably obvious, too, but the RB211 on eBay is presumably not in working order (it's being sold as a display exhibit, not as a functioning engine.) Still, nice find. :)